# C++ to Ada with pointers and exceptions

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, ada

I'm interviewing potential software engineering candidates and would like a translation into Ada of this piece of C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int *W = NULL;
  try { *W = 3; }
  catch (...) { std::cout << "default exception"; }
}
```

As with the C++ code, I want the Ada code to result in "terminated by signal SIGSEGV".

BTW, I'm using the latest GNAT (GNAT 9.1.1 20190503 (Red Hat 9.1.1-1)
)

Comment: What's the point of that try/catch?

Comment: "*As with the C++ code, I want the Ada code to result in "terminated by signal SIGSEGV"*" - why? The C++ code is neither required not particularly expected to throw the SIGSEGV. You're just invoking undefined behaviour and I have absolutely no idea what is the purpose of your `try-catch`. It will not catch the exception of dereferencing the null pointer, because there is no such exception. It's undefined behaviour, once again.

Comment: By the way - what's the question..?

Comment: You’ve made my point. In interviews I’ve asked the result of that C++ code to dozens of candidates and most tell me it’s the cout print. They’ve memorized every detail they can about that bloated beast, C++, and don’t understand basic comp sci. They think an OS signal will be caught by an C++ exception handler.

Comment: It really depends on which architecture you are running the C++ code in.  On the older HPUX and IBM XLC compilers, assignment to NULL is allowed and you will not get an exception.

Comment: @jski As you now have two valid answers, would you mind choose one as accepted and close the question ?

Answer (score 6):

The corresponding code in Ada would be something like

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure SigSegV is
   type Int_Ptr is access Integer;

   W : Int_Ptr := null;
begin
   W.all := 3;
exception
   when others =>
      Put_Line ("default exception");
end SigSegV;
```

But it doesn't trigger a SIGSEGV signal and you get the message as expected.
Moreover, the compiler already warned you :

```
sigsegv.adb:8:04: warning: null value not allowed here
sigsegv.adb:8:04: warning: "Constraint_Error" will be raised at run time
```

So I am not sure that you can get the same behaviour than in C++ with Ada code... Apart from calling C++ from Ada :D

Comment: To me, this is why Ada is way ahead of most languages for years, here you see : 1- “pointers” explicit called ’access’ types (you can’t ‘++’; BTW think of  ’access constant’, or even the ’not null access’, or combinations), 2- with a clear wording to handle its content (‘.all’), 3- clear warning/error at compile time (99.9%). This kind of exercises enlightens one of the reasons Ada language exists in the first place: get rid of cryptic dark magic C/C++/exotic language stuff that needs complex coding rules, code checkers, and insane expertise/maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

```ada
with Ada.Wide_Wide_Text_IO; use Ada.Wide_Wide_Text_IO;
with System;

procedure SigSegV is
   W : Integer with Import, Address => System.Null_Address;
begin
   W := 3;
exception
   when others =>
      Put_Line ("default exception");
end SigSegV;
```

SIGSEGV is converted to Standard.Storage_Error

Comment: Love this one as it shows how weird it can be to mess up with pointers in Ada :D

Answer (score 1):

Having spent years working with C++ and only just recently Ada, I believe if given a choice of a plane with its avionics written in Ada or one with its avionics written C++, I'd jump on the Ada plane. I've watched C++ grow with every release of a new standard ever more complex and, consequently, ever more unmanageable.

Ada is simple (compared to C++) and hence, much easier to manage. I'm not sure what C++ advantages exist vs Ada? None is the obvious answer.

It's a shame the DoD completely mismanaged Ada when it was first introduced. If they'd only paid Borland to develop a "Turbo Ada" and then given it away.